# iOS frequency of taking photos vs video

Tags: ios, iphone, video

I am a beginner iOS developer working as a developer on a research project. We want to be able to take several photos within a couple seconds, but also want full control on adjusting the frequency of photos taken per second.

What are the limitations put in place of the number of photos the iPhone can take per second via the regular camera (not burst or tkmelapse)? Is there a maximum value?

Or is there a way to control the frequency of capturing in video?